# Multiplying matrixes of different dimensions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to invert the following matrix in Python using the single value decomposition and i need to multiply these matrix to obtain the initial matrix just for confirmation. How can i do so while the matrices has different dimensions?

```
   X_b= [[array([2.52390408]), array([2.4962137]), array([2.46467486]), array([2.48760957])], [array([2.52390408]), array([2.4962137]), array([2.46467486]), array([2.48760957])]]
```

I used the command

```
svd=linalg.svd(x_b, full_matrices=True, compute_uv=True, hermitian=False)
```

And the results was

a=svd[0]

```
a =[[ 0.50615947 -0.50060626 -0.49428127 -0.49888074]
  [ 0.50060626  0.83361215 -0.16428559 -0.16581433]
  [ 0.49428127 -0.16428559  0.8377901  -0.16371932]
  [ 0.49888074 -0.16581433 -0.16371932  0.83475721]]]
```

b=svd[1]

```
b= [[4.98638127]
 [4.98638127]]
```

c=svd[2]

```
c= [[[1.]]

 [[1.]]]
```

I apply the same method for the example

```
R = [[190.93095651 189.30517758] [187.01785506 185.38861727] [183.29225361 181.47205695]] 

u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(R, full_matrices=True)
```

When i tried to reconstruct it using print((u * s) @ vh) i got the error

```
" operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (2,)"
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense unless you provide exact guidelines on how the padding is performed for each of the operands. Also what is the desired output?

Comment: Is it not a rule in matrix algebra that you need 1 dimension to be equal to one another?
Matrix 1 and 2 have dimensions 2x3, and 3X5. Both have 1 dimension of 3, thus the output matrix is 2x5.
Your matrixes are 4x4, and 1x2. I do not understand what matrix C has.
Basically I am saying you cannot multiply these matrices together because of their dimensions.

Comment: @CliffordPiehl - The question is *how can I add zeros [...] to perform the multiplication*.

Comment: @Ivan I edited the post could you please check it

Comment: @CliffordPiehl I edited the post could you please check it

Comment: Can you provide `x_b`?

Comment: @Ivan X_b is the matrix i need to invert

Comment: @Ivan Thank you for the clarification, i need now to invers the matrix x_b, I transported u and vh and as s is one dimension i left it as it as, I tried to multiply (vh_1 * s_1) @ u_1 but I got an error massage " operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4) (2,)

Comment: Please take another look at the example I gave: you are required to slice the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation page of `numpy.linalg.svd` it is explained how to reconstruct the input matrix using the returned values of `svd`:

> `linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=True, compute_uv=True, hermitian=False)`
>
> *Parameters*:
>
> - `a` (…, M, N) `array_like`
>   A real or complex array with `a.ndim >= 2`.
>
> *Returns*:
>
> - `u` { (…, M, M), (…, M, K) } `array`
>   Unitary array(s). The first `a.ndim` - 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input `a`. The size of the last two dimensions depends on the value of `full_matrices`. Only returned when `compute_uv` is `True`.
> - `s` (…, K) `array` 
>   Vector(s) with the singular values, within each vector sorted in descending order. The first `a.ndim` - 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input `a`.
> - `vh` { (…, N, N), (…, K, N) } `array` 
>   Unitary array(s). The first `a.ndim` - 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input `a`. The size of the last two dimensions depends on the value of `full_matrices`. Only returned when `compute_uv` is `True`.
>
> [...]
> When `a` is a 2D array, it is factorized as `u @ np.diag(s) @ vh = (u * s) @ vh`, where u and `vh` are 2D unitary arrays and s is a 1D array of `a`’s singular values. When a is higher-dimensional, SVD is applied in stacked mode [...].

---

You can adapt the given examples to your use case:

```
>>> X_b = np.array([[[2.52390408], [2.4962137], [2.46467486], [2.48760957]],
                    [[2.52390408], [2.4962137], [2.46467486], [2.48760957]]])

>>> u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(X_b[...,0], full_matrices=True)
>>> u.shape, s.shape, vh.shape
((2, 2), (2,), (4, 4))
```

Reconstructing `X_b`:

```
>>> (u * s) @ vh[:2,:]
array([[2.52390408, 2.4962137 , 2.46467486, 2.48760957],
       [2.52390408, 2.4962137 , 2.46467486, 2.48760957]])

>>> np.allclose((u * s) @ vh[:2,:], X_b[...,0])
True
```

Comment: I apply the same method for the example R = [[190.93095651 189.30517758]
 [187.01785506 185.38861727]
 [183.29225361 181.47205695]] 
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(R, full_matrices=True)
When i tried to reconstruct it using print((u * s) @ vh) i got the error " operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (2,)"

Comment: Can you edit your question with this example as well as the corresponding error backtrace?

Comment: i edit the post